# Composed function ..

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given a function $f: \mathbf{N}_0 \to \mathbf{N}_0$, defined
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+3 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{even}} \\
x-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{odd}}
\end{cases}
$$

Is the composed function $f o f = x + 2$ if $x ∈ {N}_0$ ?

Comment: @ArsenBerk he just forgot to make some spaces: It should be $x+2$ if $x \in N_0$.

Comment: Ah, okay now I see.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. If you want to justify it, simply note that for $x$ even and $y$ odd we always have $x+y$ is odd.

Comment: I already justified it by doing the composition.

Comment: Well, then I guess you solved it correctly. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider:

- If $x$ is even, then $f(x) = x+3$ will give us an odd number and $f(f(x)) = (x+3)-1 = x+2$.
- If $x$ is odd, then $f(x) = x-1$ will give us an even number and $f(f(x)) = (x-1)+3 = x+2$.

Therefore, in general, $f\circ f = x+2$. So you're correct.